# Issue updating state reactively in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, state-management, vue-reactivity

Creating a Vuejs application whereby I use Vuex for state management between the components.In Vuex store, I have an action that fetches some data from an API (which works fine) then populate it to the state (via a mutation). Next, I pass the updated state to the component using getters.

Am having a problem populating data to the state (reactive manner) from the action (via mutation). In the DOM when I log the getter am getting an empty string.

Vuex Store

```
const getDefaultState = () => {
    return {
        clientDeposit: ''
    }
}


//state
const state = getDefaultState();


//getters
const getters = {
    getDeposit: (state) => state.clientDeposit
}

//actions
const actions = {
    fetchClients({ commit}) {

       const clientId ="23"
       axios.post('/api/motor/fetchClients', {
         ClientId: clientId,
        })
         .then((response)=> {
          
          //console.log(response);  //returns data

          const deposit = response.data;
          commit('setDeposit', deposit);
        })
    }
}

//mutations 
const mutations = {
    setDeposit: (state, value) => (state.clientDeposit = value)
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
        <button onclick="fetchClients()">Fetch Clients</button> 
        Deposit (Via computed property) : {{ fetchDeposit }}     
        Deposit (from getter) : {{ getDeposit }}         
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters , mapActions } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "",
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
        "getDeposit"
    ]),
    fetchDeposit(){
        return this.getDeposit
    },
  },
  methods:{
    ...mapActions([
        "fetchClients"
    ])
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Strange ! This should work. Do you have this project somewhere so that I can have a look at it, if possible ? Also, check if store initialization is done properly.

Comment: @Vipulw Very strange,, has costed me hours debugging. I dont have it hosted online. From your view, do you think getDeposit getter should be reactive the way its structured..

Comment: Yes, this should work. This is how I use. I think we are missing a minor thing. See if you can share code on github maybe.

Comment: @Vipulw I have logged and found out its updating the Vue state, the problem is on the component,its not reactive (changing immediately when the Vuex state has changed)

Comment: Change in state is reactive in DOM. Make ```this.getDeposits``` a function